# The CORS error occurred on SignalR negotiation phase

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following error in Console after migration from Asp.net core 2.2 to 3.1

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'someuri/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from 
origin 'http://localhost:4208' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource.
```

And the following `SignalR` configuration:

```
app.UseCors(Constants.Policy);
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseEndpoints(
          endpoints =>
          {
             endpoints.MapHub<SomeHub>("/ws/someuri");
          });
```

I've added the following policy:

```
options.AddPolicy(Constants.Policy,
                    p => 
                        p.AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials()
                       .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4208"));
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the `CORS` this way and the order is **important!**

On your configure method:

```cs
public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, HostConfiguration hostConfiguration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    base.Configure(app, hostConfiguration, logger);

    app.UseWebSockets();

    app.UseCors(CorsPolicy); // first configure CORS, then map Hub

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<SomeHub>("/someuri");
    });
}
```

Then when adding CORS:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds the CORS.
/// </summary>
private void AddCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy, builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4208")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true));
    });
}
```

You can see more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937461/signalr-core-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-azure-app-service/59939270#59939270).

Comment: Thanks, I will try, but should I update Angular SignalR package ??

Comment: @VladislavFurdak the client package was migrated from ```@aspnet/signalr``` to ```@microsoft/signalr``` so you should upgrade the package to version 3.1.3: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr

Comment: Then remove the ```ws``` from the uri.

Comment: Also please add you angular code how you connect to the server.

Comment: I found that context.Request.Query["access_token"] returns NULL after migration from 2.2 to 3.1

Comment: How you pass the token on client side? Did you have authorization atribute? As I said before, please add your client side code.

Comment: connection =
      new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.url, {
          accessTokenFactory: () => this.token
        })
        .withAutomaticReconnect(new RetryPolicy())
        .build();